# Cisco IOS: Show incoming Telnet sessions

Tags: cisco, ios, telnet, session

According to `show ?` the `show sessions` command is supposed to show `Information about Telnet connections`. Although I'm connected, the sessions does not show up. Both devices run Cisco IOS. How can I look up current Telnet sessions?

On the router running the Telnet server:

```
 Router2#debug telnet 
 Incoming Telnet debugging is on
 Router2#
 Router2#
 Oct 25 13:34:59.063: Telnet226: 1 1 251 1
 Oct 25 13:34:59.063: TCP226: Telnet sent WILL ECHO (1)
 Oct 25 13:34:59.063: Telnet226: 2 2 251 3
 Oct 25 13:34:59.063: TCP226: Telnet sent WILL SUPPRESS-GA (3)
 Oct 25 13:34:59.063: Telnet226: 80000 80000 253 24
 Oct 25 13:34:59.063: TCP226: Telnet sent DO TTY-TYPE (24)
 Oct 25 13:34:59.063: Telnet226: 10000000 10000000 253 31
 Oct 25 13:34:59.063: TCP226: Telnet sent DO WINDOW-SIZE (31)
 Oct 25 13:34:59.071: TCP226: Telnet received DO SUPPRESS-GA (3)
 Oct 25 13:34:59.075: TCP226: Telnet received WILL TTY-LOCATION (23) (refused)
 Oct 25 13:34:59.079: TCP226: Telnet sent DONT TTY-LOCATION (23)
 Oct 25 13:34:59.083: TCP226: Telnet received WILL TTY-SPEED (32) (refused)
 Oct 25 13:34:59.087: TCP226: Telnet sent DONT TTY-SPEED (32)
 Oct 25 13:34:59.091: TCP226: Telnet received WILL WINDOW-SIZE (31)
 Oct 25 13:34:59.091: TCP226: Telnet received WILL LOCAL-FLOW (33)
 Oct 25 13:34:59.095: TCP226: Telnet sent DO LOCAL-FLOW (33)
 Oct 25 13:34:59.099: Telnet226: Sent SB 33 0 
 Oct 25 13:34:59.099: TCP226: Telnet received DO ECHO (1)
 Oct 25 13:34:59.103: TCP226: Telnet received WONT TTY-TYPE (24)
 Oct 25 13:34:59.103: TCP226: Telnet sent DONT TTY-TYPE (24)
 Oct 25 13:34:59.103: Telnet226: recv SB NAWS 80 24
 Oct 25 13:34:59.107: TCP226: Telnet received WONT TTY-LOCATION (23)
 Oct 25 13:34:59.115: TCP226: Telnet received WONT TTY-SPEED (32)
 Router2#
 Router2#
 Router2#show sessions
 % No connections open
 Router2#
```

On the router connected to the Telnet server:

```
 Router2>show sessions
 % No connections open
 Router2>
 Router2>
 Router2>enable
 Password: 
 Router2#     
 Router2#show sessions
 % No connections open
 Router2#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for:

`show users` (or like most would type `sh users`)

Answer (score 4):

`show sessions` will display outgoing connections from your switch/router to other devices.

`show users` will display incoming connections to the vty interfaces (ssh/telnet...) of your switch/router.

So i think you need `show users` here.

Answer (score 2):

Other useful ways to see who is connected would include `who`, `show line` and `show ssh`. For detailed info on connections you can use `show tcp`.

Answer (score 1):

Many IOS versions also support the who and where commands.
Who displays the same output as show users.
Where displays the same output as show sessions